# Regex for Gmail email addresses that start with first name followed by a random number

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

We are looking for fake accounts in our database and notice that almost all of them follow this pattern for email addresses:

```
email = firstname + (a random number) + '@gmail.com'
```

Where `firstname` is a column in the same table

E.g., if somebody's first name is Lukas then his email address is something like `lukas123@gmail.com`

Could you help me with an Sql query containing a regex that gives us the count of these users?

Comment: Why would you assume an address with numbers after the name/prior to the `@` are fake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE firstname + '%[0-9]@gmail.com'
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4de7b/1)